# Custom UIView in Code

Tags: ios, uiview

Ive created a `UIView` in code using the `addSubview:view` method. If I want this to be a custom  class rather than the standard `UIView`, does all this customisation have to take place in the view controllers `viewDidLoad` method? Seems like there will be alot of code in the `viewDidLoad` if this is the case! This is the first time ive attempted to create a view in code - the other times ive done it in IB where Ive created a custom class and changed the class of the view in the identity inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new UIView subclass

```
// MyView.h
@interface MyView : UIView
// public properties, method declarations here
@end

// MyView.m
@implementation MyView
// implementation here, including anything you want to customize this view's
// look or behavior
@end
```

Then instantiate it in your view controller by importing and referring to the custom class

```
// ViewController.m
#import "MyView.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

Comment: So simple, im such a divvy sometimes! I was thinking I was going to have to do all the guff thats normally in the class in the viewdidload section of the view controller. But this way makes alot more sense! thankyou!